# select other column which having min value in subquery

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to select other column which having MIN value in subquery?
In my subquery, i produce lists of value. Then how to get the time that I produce that value

here is my code :

```
Select A, (select Time from result where value = ??MIN VALUE), MIN (value)
from (
      //subquery
     ) result
group by A
```

Examples of data that my Subquery produces :

```
A              Time                       Value
ABC     2016-10-26 15:00:00.000             10
ABC     2016-10-26 15:00:01.000             5
ABC     2016-10-26 15:00:02.000             15
DEF     2016-10-26 15:00:05.000             20
DEF     2016-10-26 15:00:06.000             25
```

Expected Result :

```
A              Time                       Value
ABC     2016-10-26 15:00:01.000             5
DEF     2016-10-26 15:00:05.000             20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT s.a,s.time,s.value
FROM(
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.a ORDER BY t.time) as rnk
    FROM YourTable t) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
```

If ties are possible, replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()`

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 with ties a,time,value
from
table
order by row_number() over (partition by a order by value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RANK():

```
DECLARE @tblTest AS TABLE(
    A VARCHAR(5),
    Value INT
)

INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES
('ABC',10),
('ABC',5),
('ABC',15),
('DEF',20),
('DEF',25),
('GHI',20),
('GHI',7),
('GHI',7)

;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        RANK() OVER(Partition By A ORDER BY Value) AS PartNo
    FROM @tblTest
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM T
WHERE T.PartNo=1
```

**Output:**

[image]